# IPv6 connectivity lost

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv6

I have an ARM server at home that gets a IPv6 assigned from my router. With this IP it is accessible from the internet. However after some hours I notice that he is not accessible anymore and if I SSH into the server I see that only my IPv6 link-local address is set.

I don't know how this can happen or how I can debug it. Any help is much appreciated!

My configuration:

- Pi4
- Raspbian OS
- docker installed (running containers, maybe they can interfere?)
- dhcpcd.conf:

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.5/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.254
```

After startup:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2003:de:[...]:9780  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::7243:dc77:431d:76eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:c5:c9:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 92  bytes 11278 (11.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 116  bytes 16329 (15.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

After some time:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::7243:dc77:431d:76eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:c5:c9:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24261450  bytes 1315486709 (1.2 GiB)
        RX errors 29678  dropped 29678  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28374527  bytes 2775722882 (2.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Edit:
I found one user with the same problem on a [techrepublic forum](https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/ipv6-connectivity-lost-after-some-minutes-linux/) but without any answers.

Answer (score 0):

After removing watchtower from my running docker containers the issue did not return. I will post this in to the watchtower issue tracker and update this questions if we get it resolved.